# Children's illustrated SF book with 2 children forced to flee in an escape pod

Tags: story-identification, books, spaceship, robots

I’m looking for a children's book I read when I was aged five or six (we're talking the late 1970's/early 1980's, If I was really pushed I would say 1981 but hey... whatever...). It was a book in the school library, (this is very specifically, a British school in the North East of England, outskirts of Newcastle/Sunderland, I mention this because different regions of the UK might have had different books under different educational boards), hard backed, about fifteen pages and nicely illustrated with what I recall as watercolour images, although they might have been marker pen.

The story is as follows. Two children – a brother and sister playing in the corridor of a spaceship – are forced to climb into an escape pod when the decompression alarm sounds. They are on what seems to be a colony spaceship. The decompression seems local to their corridor as they see the ship is basically undamaged as they fly away.

The pod automatically takes them to the nearest safe place which is a large seemingly abandoned ship floating in space. Here, they meet dangerous robots. There is a scene in which the boy finds a gun, which is so powerful it slices a pursuing robot in half. This was colourfully illustrated.

One of the robots declares it will destroy the human ship and flies off in a fighter. The children follow in the hope they can warn their ship. The children's father has already begun looking for them, spots the fighter and destroys it. They all live happily ever after.

OK, so not a ground breaking story but one that I had great affection for. I read it in English in the UK. I remember neither the title nor the author, but I'm hoping someone on this site recognizes it.